# CSS - Styling small details with <p>

Tags: html, css

I need to make something like this:

[image: How it should looks like]

I actually made something like this: 
[image]

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/sLcK9/2/

It looks my only problem right now is to put the button and that text "4x reakce" on the same line and to the right positions, but I just can't help my self, is there a chance you can help me with it?

My HTML:

```
<span id="article-container">

<ul>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/foto.jpg" width="109" height="109" alt="Popis"></a>
            <h2><a href="#">Název článku</a></h2>
            <p><span><strong>28. 2. 2014 8:29</strong> od Dwandy</span><br>
              Ahoj, jak se máš? Já úplně úžasně a úpe nejvíc. Závidíš, he? </p>
            <p class="more"><a href="#" class="links">Přečíst</a><br>
              <a href="#">4 reakce</a></p>
            <hr>
       </li>

  <li><a href="#"><img src="images/foto.jpg" alt="Popis"></a>
           <h2><a href="#">Název článku</a></h2>
           <p><span><strong>28. 2. 2014 8:29</strong> od Dwandy</span><br>
             Ahoj, jak se máš? Já úplně úžasně a úpe nejvíc. Závidíš, he? </p>
           <p class="more"><a href="#" class="links">Přečíst</a><br>
             <a href="#">4 reakce</a></p>
           <hr>
      </li>

      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/foto.jpg" alt="Popis"></a>
           <h2><a href="#">Název článku</a></h2>
           <p><span><strong>28. 2. 2014 8:29</strong> od Dwandy</span><br>
             Ahoj, jak se máš? Já úplně úžasně a úpe nejvíc. Závidíš, he? </p>
           <p class="more"><a href="#" class="links">Přečíst</a><br>
             <a href="#">4 reakce</a></p>
           <hr>
      </li>
 </ul>
```

CSS:

```
#article-container{
  width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color:#4d4d4d;
    font-size:90%
  height: 144px;
}

#article-container br, hr {
    display:none;
}
#article-container ul {
    width:960px;
  height: 144px
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:15px 0;
}
#article-container li {
    width:320px;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0
}
#article-container img {
    float:left;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0
}
#article-container a img {
    border:2px solid #999e8a
}
#article-container a:hover img {
    border-color:#000
}
#article-container h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    font-size:110%;
    font-weight:normal;
}
#article-container h2 a {
    color:#4d4d4d
}
#article-container h2 a:hover {
    color:#840000
}
#article-container p {
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    margin:0
}
#article-container p span {
    display:block;
    padding: 0 0 5px 0
}
#article-container p.more {
    padding: 0px 0 0 0;
    overflow:hidden
}
#article-container p.more a {
    color:#2e79bc
}
#article-container p.more a:hover {
    color:#840000
}
#article-container p.more a.links {
    float:right;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background:#2e79bc;
    color:#fff;
    margin-right:15px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-radius:3px;
}
#article-container p.more a.links:hover {
    background:#000
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

changing the line height worked for me :

```
#article-container p.more a {
    color:#2e79bc;
    line-height: 27px; /* try changing this and see what happens */
}

#article-container p.more a.links {
    float:right;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background:#2e79bc;
    color:#fff;
    margin-right:15px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-radius:3px;
    line-height: 18px; /* try changing this and see what happens */
}
```

demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/sLcK9/4/

Comment: Hey mate, your code is really helpfull , the first one help me to change position of a text and second one of button, but both just vertical not horizontal even if i change value

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sLcK9/3/)**

```
#article-container{
    width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
color:#4d4d4d;
    height: 144px;
}
```

Comment: mate  thanks for trzing to help me. But i see no change in zour article-container and my one. I just have font-size:90% there and u dont, i trz to delete it but nothing changed :(

Comment: I did it works on fiddle for zou, but idk what else u changed :)

Comment: I actualy start afraid i have something defined in other part of my CSS :(

Answer (score -1):

Replace the below CSS with exisitng one's:

```
#article-container p {
    margin:0
}

#article-container p.more {
    overflow:hidden
}
```